# Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/university_website/index_xml.php,

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am trying to get some data from a database to be formatted as XML. I am pulling the XML file which has the data from the database by using `DOCDocument` along with an XML stylesheet.

**The full errors I am getting are:**

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/university_website/index_xml.php, line: 10 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/university_website/xmltrans.php on line 4
```

**index_xml.php contains**

```
<?php
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
require_once __DIR__ . ('/config/init.php');

$mysqli = new mysqli($db['hostname'], $db['username'], $db['password'], $db['database']);
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
        }
$_xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
$_xml = "<news>";

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE live = '1'")) {
    while($news = $result->fetch_array()){ 
        $_xml .= "<news_id>".$news['id']."</news_id>";
        $_xml .= "<title>" .$news['title']."</title>";
        $_xml .= "<content>" .$news['content']."</content>";
        $_xml .= "<live>" .$news['live']."</live>";
    } 
    $result->close();
} 

$_xml .= "</news>";

$xml = simplexml_load_string($_xml);
//$xmlobj = new SimpleXMLElement($_xml);
print $xml->asXML();

?>
```

If I navigate to `index_xml.php` this page on it's own it displays correctly without style.

`xmltrans.php` which brings the xml file and the XLST together contains the following code. If I navigate to this page I get the error seen above.

```
<?php

$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('index_xml.php');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl -> load('style.xsl');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor;

$proc -> importStyleSheet($xsl);

echo $proc -> transformToXML($xml);

?>
```

Any ideas whats causing the issue?

Comment: `$xml->load()` is reading the contents of your `index_xml.php` rather than the output. Try loading from the URL.

Comment: Top stuff, that sorted it. Cheers!

Comment: On a side note: you are doing `$_xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; $_xml = "<news>";`. The second assignment should likely be a `.=` because it overwrites the previous assignment, e.g. you are overwriting the xml prolog.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is to curl your XML page.

```
$url = 'http://localhost/index_xml.php';

function getUrlContent($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; 
Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
return ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) ? $data : false;
}
```

Then access your XML Document object with this function below.

```
simplexml_load_string(getURLContent($url));
```

Sources: 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php